# Azure Angularjs Website + Nancyfx + SQL Databases deployment strategies

Tags: angularjs, git, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed an Website built with angularjs and a Web Service Running Nancyfx framework rather than the "suggested" Web Api. I also use 2 SQL Databases.

I did this from Visual Studio where I have my project running. However the app (still in development) was developed locally on my mac and then just copied in visual studio.

Since I would be working with a friend of mine on it (who also uses mac) and we already have it on bitbucket with Git (my local version) I was wondering if it was possible to 'Set up deployment from source control' but only for the "website" part, meaning the angularjs. The web service needs to obviously be deployed from Visual Studio (I'm the only one working on that part).

Is there any way to achieve this? If I set up deployment from source control and then publish to the website from visual studio, would this override the existing version and current deployment last updated from Git? will it get denied publishing since it's set up from Git?

I am not sure how to better approach this.

The dirty way would be to set git for me and my friend on my local "app" folder of my Visual Studio solution so that I get his changes and then it's my job to publish it to azure via Visual Studio.

Comment: You can do the visual studio build step on your website rather than using visual studio. Simply git push your repo to your site, and if it's a regular web app it should recognize it automatically, build it, and deploy it for you. If it doesn't, you still can generate a custom deployment script that achieves that on the server side

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean ahmelsayed. What I am trying to achieve is updating the "webservice(nancyfx) part" from Visual Studio while avoiding that pushing the angularjs app (in which case should I just delete the "app" folder from my VS project?) to then push the angularjs app changes via github (either mine or my colleague).

Comment: I was questioning updating the webservice part from Visual Studio. But I guess I don't quite understand your layout. Do you have everything in 1 VS project?

Comment: I was not sure what was the practice to deploying angularjs apps to azure website so I built after a template I found. So my project looks like this: http://puu.sh/bY7Qb/876b543cc7.png  So Yes, my angularjs app is in the same project as my webservice as i thought it had to be as such to be deployed on azure websites. But now I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428799/publish-webapi-and-mvc-projects-to-same-azure-web-site and I guess i could/should follow that strategy?

Comment: your approach should also be fine. try publishing your app using git rather than Visual Studio. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step4 this will allow you to use your azure website as a build server as well, so you can work on your mac and have the server build your project for you. ASP.NET apps should work fine, I never tried pushing a NancyFx app but it might work. give it a try

Comment: Turned out that what i needed is exactly this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428799/publish-webapi-and-mvc-projects-to-same-azure-web-site 

I therefore split my webservice (API) project so it's by itself and published that to mywebsite/api while my app resides on mywebsite/app so that I can publish my webservice changes from visual studio without problems, and also publish the changes to my angularjs app via git. 

I haven't encountered any downside atm of doing this but it seems to me this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that what i needed is exactly this: [Publish WebAPI and MVC projects to same Azure Web Site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428799/publish-webapi-and-mvc-projects-to-same-azure-web-site)

I therefore split my webservice (API) project so it's by itself and published that to mywebsite/api while my app resides on mywebsite/app so that I can publish my webservice changes from visual studio without problems, and also publish the changes to my angularjs app via git.

I haven't encountered any downside atm of doing this but it seems this is the best approach.