# Run two different ASP.NET 5 applications under the same Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have had a look at this question:
[Publish WebAPI and MVC projects to same Azure Web Site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428799/publish-webapi-and-mvc-projects-to-same-azure-web-site)

but it doesn not work properly for the "secondary" application.

and from that I learned about virtual directories in Azure web app services ( previously called Azure websites).

I am trying to deploy into the same Azure web apps 2 web applications. Both are ASP.NET 5 applications (they will be MVC 6) under a solution called MyOAuth:

- MyApi: ASP.NET 5 application that should be accessible through **myoauth.azurewebsites.com**
- MyAuth: ASP.NET 5 application that should be accessible through **myoauth.azurewebsites.com/oauth**

> ```
> Solution 'MyOAuth'
>   |-src
>      |- MyApi
>      |- MyAuth
> ```

So in the Azure Web App service that I have created (called also **MyOAuth**), under settings I have the following Virtual Applications and Directories:

```
/        site\wwwroot         Application
/oauth   site\wwwroot\oauth   Application
```

The Publish connection from Visual Studio 2015 for both of them are:

- MyApi

> ```
> Server: myoauth.scm.azurewebsites.net:443
> Site Name: MyOAuth
> User Name: *****
> Password: ****
> Destination URL: http://myoauth.azurewebsites.net
> ```

- MyOAuth

> ```
> Server: myoauth.scm.azurewebsites.net:443
> Site Name: MyOAuth/oauth
> User Name: *****
> Password: ****
> Destination URL: http://myoauth.azurewebsites.net/oauth
> ```

These are the Startup configuration for both projects:

**Startup.cs for MyApi**

```
//...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello MyApi app");
    });
}
```

**Startup.cs for MyAuth**

```
//...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("...And hello MyAuth app");
    });
}
```

After publishing, when I access http://myoauth.azurewebsites.net I get the proper response `Hello MyApi app`, but when requesting http://myoauth.azurewebsites.net/oauth I get a server 500 error with text `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

I managed to retrieve the following DetailedError from the Azure LogFiles folder:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       IIS Web Core 
>   Notification  BeginRequest 
>   Handler      Not yet determined 
>   Error Code       0x800700b7
>   Config Error     Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add'
>   with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'httpplatformhandler' Config
>   File     \?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\oauth\web.config Requested URL
>   http://MyOAuth:80/oauth Physical Path    D:\home\site\wwwroot\oauth
>   Logon Method     Not yet determined Logon User       Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:
>
> ```
> <handlers>
>   <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
> </handlers>
> ```

Could anybody advise on this or give me a solution on how to run 2 different ASP.NET 5 applications under the same Azure Web App Service, please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Its possible following the folder structure outlined here:

https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/928#issuecomment-171617386

THe problem is that I have yet not found tooling that makes it easy to do with vs2015 or VSTeamServices

One of the key things that I had to do to make it work (still did some manual deployments steps - but i found one issue in my setup that could help you also i think). The following will fix the 500.19 error

```
    <handlers>
      <remove name="httpplatformhandler" />
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
```

More information on same topic can be found at: [Deploying aspnet5 apps to virtual directories on azure websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784391/deploying-aspnet5-apps-to-virtual-directories-on-azure-websites/34799414#34799414)

Comment: I still don't fully understand what changes are required. As per your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784391/deploying-aspnet5-apps-to-virtual-directories-on-azure-websites
the structure in Azure having the app0 with ```wwwroot/web.config``` and the app1 (called oauth in my case) with ```wwwroot/oauth/web.config``` seems to be causing the issue for app1.
Are you saying I have to manually change the folder/file structure directly in Azure to have it working?

Comment: I am saying that I havent yet made it work with the tooling that default are in visual studio. I just got an example working with 3 apps, but this involved msdeploy from command line. I will update answer with some more information as I find it.