# Deploying aspnet5 apps to virtual directories on azure websites

Tags: powershell, azure, msdeploy, asp.net-core

The default folder structure when deploying with the new powershell publish tools for none virtual directories are

```
/data
/LogFiles
/site
/site/appRoot
/site/wwwroot
/site/wwwroot/web.config
/site/locks
/site/deployments
```

then when deploying a new app into a virtual directory:
[image]

the structure becomes

```
/site/wwwroot/approot
/site/wwwroot/testvirt
/site/wwwroot/testvirt/web.config
```

is this the intended way to have virtual dirs approots in the wwwroot folder?
Is there any flexibility in the placement of approot. What happens when adding the next virtual application, looking at file structure it woulld overwrite the approot of the first virtual application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related information to this can be found : https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/928#issuecomment-171617386

I managed to get 3 virtual apps running side by side by setting the virtual directory settings on azure portal like the following:
[image]

Then I deployed my webapp to all 3 for test using commandline in the same way that visual studio is doing it.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:IisApp='C:\Users\pks\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\appname53' -dest:IisApp='appname/app2',ComputerName='https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd',UserName='$appname',Password='',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -enableLink:contentLibExtension  -retryAttempts:2
```

and manually copyed over web.config to parent folder as indicated in the github suggesting from @davidfowl.

So currently its not possible directly with visual studio tooling to publish this behavior. It should be posible to get it working with visual studio if only the root and one additional virtual app is needed. If wanting more than that the approots folders will conflict.

I also ran into an error (not sure if it was due to alot of manual web.config copying) that the virtual applications had the httpplatform handler added already and it started throwing 500 errors and the fix was to update web.config

```
 <handlers>
      <remove name="httpplatformhandler" />
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the Azure web app service virtual application directory. In Azure, the following handler would always be appended in the sub virtual application's web.config, regardless!

```
<handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

The trick is the remove the handler "aspNetCore" by adding the following code using the following code:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
</handlers>
```