# How to host website and webapi using PAAS model on windows azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

I have a asp.net website and web api project. I am trying to host them on windows azure using the PAAS model. At present in my local dev environment I have hosted the website and web api as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]
Both the asp.net website and web api are attached to different Visual Studio Solutions. The web api project is referenced within the asp.net website.
At present for website I use Visual Studio 2013 for publishing the package. I want to host the web site and the web api in the same pattern done in local dev envrionment on azure using the PAAS model.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you check this answer? This might give you a way to host them both on the same Azure web app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428799/publish-webapi-and-mvc-projects-to-same-azure-web-site

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In VS2015 and possibly in VS2013Z(I cannot confirm since I don't have it installed anymore), you can just right click on the API/web project and select 'Publish' in the context menu. In the 'Publish Web' dialog, select the 'Microsoft Azure App Service'. Follow the instructions in selecting your azure account and resource group.

Not quite if this is what your are looking for.