# Can't resolve "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies" with documentation found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, botframework

I tried to deploy two ASP.NET web projects (a Facebook app and a bot) to the same Azure web site but, after I got them both deployed I received:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm not sure what I can do other than start all over and merge the two projects into a single project (not desirable) to republish. So far I've:

1. Installed, via NuGet, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc as suggested in other threads. Both projects have versions 5.2.3.0 on them
2. Ensured the Web.config files have 5.2.3.0 on them

Bot

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

App

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

3. Ensured property "Copy Local" is set to "True" on both projects for reference System.Web.Mvc

Here's the stack trace:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc'
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +92    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10044576
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: It is possible that incorrect binding was used in `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />` for both apps. Try changing `newVersion` attribute value to either 5.0.0.0 or 5.1.0.0 depending what version will work later.

Comment: Sorry, neither version work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try going to https://[YourSiteName].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell

And execute the following @ the PowerShell prompt:

```
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll").FileVersion
```

This will tell you what version the .Mvc.dll is.

Note: your live site files are under \site\wwwroot\

Comment: I tried changing the Mvc.dll line on the web.config to the version response from PowerShell, 5.2.20826.0. After publishing, it still did not work.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the deployment files completely, and re-deploying?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved to start my web projects from scratch and see if I could solve this error. I was able to find this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428799/publish-webapi-and-mvc-projects-to-same-azure-web-site) on how to deploy two projects to a single Azure web site. The idea is to create a virtual directory under the main web site and publish your web site to the root web site and, in my case the bot, to the virtual directory. So far it seems to hold!